# Is adding a that clause to these clauses valid?

Tags: clauses, that

I am unsure whether I can use that-clauses or zero-that-clauses like this:

> 1. I noticed (that) when we heard (that) to make noise would be forbidden was surprising.
> 2. I told him (that) **what I saw (that)** she was pregnant was surprising.

It sounds a little odd to me (specifically the bold part). Are these sentences wrong or valid?

Comment: I'm afraid both sentences sound wrong. But the main problem is not the *that*s but the whole sentence.

Comment: These ungrammatical sentences have too many predicates (five in #1, and four in 2), and no clear connections between them.

Answer (score 0):

The use or omission of *that* is often a matter of style, not grammar, so it isn't the stern application of a rule. For example, "I noticed that she was pregnant." and "I noticed she was pregnant." are both acceptable, though the first is probably preferred for formal writing.

There are, of course, some instances in which leaving out the *that* can change the meaning of a sentence or simply make it difficult to parse. But many times, it's a matter of personal taste, rhythm, pacing, and voice.

As for your sentences, their problems go way beyond the use of *that*. I can't even make sense of the second one.

Here's a general tip, though, that might be useful: Unless you're deliberately trying to confuse your reader, sentences should be constructed so that later words don't require readers to reformulate or redefine earlier words. Put another way, if you read your sentence (as anyone would) one word at a time, if at any time the wording or sentence structure causes you to reread the previous words in a different light, you've probably got a problem.

Take the beginning of your second sentence, for example. Notice the difference between
"I told him what I saw..." and
"I told him that what I saw..."

If what "I" told "him" doesn't involve a description of what was seen, you should keep the *that*.